# Exporting AS3 animation to FLV using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to export an animation consisting of AS3 etc etc into a FLV file type using AS3 Code to do it rather than using manual progression

File > Export etc etc

Thanks

Aiden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a long shot, but depending on the conditions (CPU power, resolution, memory) it could work.

You should be able to make a `BitmapData` for every frame in your movie using `bitmapData.draw(displayObject);`. Then store all those bitmaps in an array, and then encode to flv using some external library such as [this one](https://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/;).

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/bddraw/) on how to convert a `displayObject` into a `BitmapData`.

If instead of using Flash Player you compile to Adobe Air for desktop, you could save the frames as files in the hard drive, and then encode the sequence using a multitude of programs (such as After Effects) to any video format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this codebase, it may save you some time:

http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/

```
var myWriter:SimpleFlvWriter = SimpleFlvWriter.getInstance();
myWriter.createFile(myFile, 320,240, 30, 120);
myWriter.saveFrame( myBitmapData1 );
myWriter.saveFrame( myBitmapData2 );
myWriter.saveFrame( myBitmapData3 ); // ... etc.
myWriter.closeFile();
```